How do I convert an I2S/TDM signal to a CAN signal
I'm getting output from the Analog Devices ADXL317 and I want to convert the output signal to a CAN signal. I don't think many CAN transceivers can take input from the I2S bus, so I need to find another way. Any help would be appreciated

Is there a microcontroller involved between the ADXL317 and CAN transceiver, or do you need something which doesn't involve writing any software?

I believe you will need a microcontroller that can support both SPI/I2C and CAN interface. You will need to process the accelerometer data.

You need to be more precise what you mean. CAN is two things, a physical interface, and a protocol. Compare that to RS-232/RS-485 PHYs with which you generally (but not always) use an UART for the bit protocol. I2S and TDM are audio streaming interfaces, CAN is not. What do you want to do, make a microphone with CAN interface?

@ChesterGillon as of right now there is no microcontroller, as I am currently using an A2B transceiver that interfaces really well with the accelerometer. I'm open to using a microcontroller if that's the best way. I'm guessing the software is not too complex?

@DRF do you know of a good microcontroller that has this capability?

@Justme I want to use CAN to interact with other modules. I'm currently using A2B, but want to consider other options like CAN

im not sure but you can check aruino even may me able to. I do not know

"I want to use CAN to interact with other modules" is so vague I can't even begin to think of a solution. Interact how? What modules? Do you want to broadcast audio to the engine control block and ABS? The only thing I can say offhand is that CAN FD is much better suitable for this kind of data, but again, A2B was designed explicitly for this, why change it?

@Maple Currently, the accelerometer is connected to a memory management module via A2B. The memory module then routes to a control module via ethernet. I want to see if I can just use CAN all the way. I assumed this was possible, which is why I asked for the best way to convert I2S to CAN. I'm now learning that using a microcontroller is probably the best way. I hope this helps now

Using MCU is not "the best way", it is the only way (other than some tricky FPGA programming) since there are no ASICs for streaming I2S via CAN. But let's say you did it. Do any of your modules have CAN interface? If yes, then your question makes no sense, because you have to use their protocol and you already know the answer. If no, then you have to have another MCU converting your messages into original protocol. Not only that, but I suspect you'd have to do some data processing to reduce bitrate, since CAN throughput is nowhere close to I2S
